# Adding ScrollView to ViewController with 2 custom Views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

[My viewController has one view with images and labels and one textView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9axF.png)

Im new in objective c.
My problem is to add ScrollView in my ViewController with 2 custom views(UIView and UITextView).(image in the link) I have tried many things posted here in Stack but nothing works for me.
Thank YOU!

Here is what i have :

```
self.scrollView.contentSize=self.scrollView.frame.size;
self.scrollView.frame=self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjusting view's frame was the technology of 5 years ago. You should never set the frame manually, not anymore. Instead start learning Autolayout and Constraints.
These tutorials may help:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2
https://www.appcoda.com/auto-layout-guide/

Comment: Yes this helped me . Thank you  ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the content size equal to the frame size before you actually set the frame, so it's probably just 0.

You need to just switch the calls around:

```
self.scrollView.frame=self.view.frame;
self.scrollView.contentSize=self.scrollView.frame.size;
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
```

The other thing to keep in mind is that because you are setting the frame of a nested view to the frame of its superview, your layout will break (or at least not do what you expect), if the origin of your superview ever changes. If the origin is `0, 0`, then you are fine for the moment, but otherwise you may want to set the subview (scrollView) frame to be equal to the superview (self.view) bounds instead of the frame, like this:

```
self.scrollView.frame=self.view.bounds
```